# Regarding performing some action based on matched condition in for loop in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, for-loop

I want to match the RFQ No passed in string with some data in table and when this matches with particular row I want to click button in that matched row but at some other column

But code is giving error

Code :

```
    String baseUrl = "https://test.transporteg.com/";
    driver.get(baseUrl);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"j_idt12:email\"]")).sendKeys("kevin@openspaceservices.com");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"j_idt12:password\"]")).sendKeys("Eg123");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"j_idt12:j_idt19\"]")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Dashboard Provider")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"rfqViewId:j_idt248_data\"]/tr/td[5]/div[1]/input")).click();

    WebElement Webtable = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"table-1\"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]"));
    List<WebElement> allElements = Webtable.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"table-1\"]/tbody/tr/td[1]"));
    System.out.println("Reached Here 1");

    System.out.println("No. of Rows in the WebTable: " + allElements.size());
    String[] RFQ_NO = {"6291/91/06/18"};

    System.out.println("Reached Here 8");
    System.out.println("All emelements count "+allElements.size());
    for (WebElement we : allElements) {
        for (int i = 0; i <= allElements.size(); i++) 
        {
            System.out.println("For loop Count"+i);
            if (we.getText().equals(RFQ_NO[i])) {
                 System.out.println("Matched at Row"+(i));

                    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"table-1\"]/tbody/tr[" + (i + 1) + "]/td[7]/a/img"))
                            .click();
                    // *[@id="table-1"]/tbody/tr[2]/td[7]/a/img

            } else {
                System.out.println("Not Matched");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

}

Error :

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at ListPackage.List_Class.main(List_Class.java:86)

Can you please help.

Comment: Complete code :

Comment: which line is 86 here?

Answer (score 0):

The error "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1" means you are trying to access an array index that doesn't exist.

Looking at the code the error is occurring due to a for loop condition line:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= allElements.size(); i++)
```

Correct replacment for the above for loop condition should be as:

```
for (int i = 0; i < allElements.size(); i++)
```

i.e. Replace `i <= allElements.size()` with `i < allElements.size()`

For more understanding refer the link :
[ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it)